# Revision Control - Footers and markings

Tags: header-footer, revision-control

I'm fairly new to TeX and I've been looking around for ways to mark revisions as in [this document](http://www.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP493Part1corr.pdf). Each page has a footer showing when it was last changed (either by the text changing or being moved) and the most recent revision(s) on any page are highlighted with a bar to the left.

I expect much of this would have to be done manually, but is there a way to mark a paragraph as "updated July 2011" and have (La)TeX somehow pick out the most recent for a page?

I'm probably being too optimistic, but perhaps someone will have a solution which works!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I've removed the thanks. This is just the style here. Thanks is best expressed by upvoting helpful comments and answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly what my [`svn-multi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/svn-multi) package is for. It provides you with the dates and revision etc. of the last change both on a per-file base and for the while document (i.e. the latest change for any input file). This of course requires that you are using [Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) for your documents. There is a fork for RCS as well [`rcs-multi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/rcs-multi).

Comment: There's also the `vc` bundle which can work for git as well.

Comment: Would it take a lot effort to port this to, say, git? I'd be interested in doing that.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: it is based on the SVN keywords i.e. `$Id$`. AFAIK VCs like git or hg don't have these by default. There is a hg extension which allows you to do it. If you produce the same keywords than there is no need to change the package.

Comment: Cool. I may take a look at this the next time I've got a couple of hours free.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: I made a [hg interface for `rcs-multi`](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/rcs-multi/raw/1e95774a3ec5/rcs-multi-hg.sty) (which is basically `svn-multi` v1.x with a slightly different format), because I couldn't make hg produce the date in the correct format. Something similar can be done for git.

Comment: That looks good. I will certainly take a look at that and  vc for git.

That would be start, but is there any way to do on a per-page basis though? If possible, I'd like to avoid reissuing a whole chapter at a time. If necessary, that would be an option though.

Comment: @Martin: It only works on a per-input-file base. The change data comes from the VC system which can't know what page in the final PDF got changed. You can add the per-file infos in the footer of course.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a proper version control system (like SVN or GiT)? This way your working copy is always updated, and what you actually typeset is the latest version. If you need to rollback to earlier revisions, you simply checkout the version you need. This is not a TeX solution, but as the source code is plain text, you can utilize the power of the various version control systems available.

Comment: I was planning on using something like that (was leaning towards git because I'm familiar from programming). It's getting revisions into the footers that I was less certain about.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness one should also add the nice gitinfo package for the usage together with git. It provides several git-related macros which you can combine, put into the footer with fancyheaders or somewhere else. It has a good description how the info is generated, most easily by some Makefile like process.